# shouldComponentUpdate() props different to render() props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have the following code:

`user reducer`

```
const initialState = {
    user: undefined,
    isFetching: true,
    error: false
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCHING_USER':
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                user: undefined
            }
        case 'FETCHING_USER_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                user: action.data
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

`actions.js`

```
export function getUser() {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        console.log('Fetching...');
        dispatch(({ type: 'FETCHING_USER' }));
        const data = await (await fetch(new Request('http://...', {
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'access-key': '<key>'
            })
        }))).json();
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCHING_USER_SUCCESS', data });
    }
}
```

`profile-picture.js`

```
@connect(state => ({ user: state.user }))
export default class ProfilePicture extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        console.log('SHOULDCOMPONENTUPDATE USER: ', this.props.user);
        return true;
    }

    render() {
        console.log('RENDER USER: ', this.props.user);
        return( ...
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
11:31:22 AM
SHOULDCOMPONENTUPDATE USER:  Object {
  "error": false,
  "isFetching": true,
  "user": undefined,
}
11:31:22 AM
RENDER USER:  Object {
  "error": false,
  "isFetching": false,
  "user": Object {
    "desiredEnvironment": null,
    "email": "abc@abc.net",
    "expectations": null,
    "firstNme": "Iuliu",
    ...
```

This happens a few times on each render with this same output. I am trying to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` to trim down on unnecessary renders. From what I can see there is that `shouldComponentUpdate` always receives the `initialState`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `shouldComponentUpdate`, you are printing `this.props.user`, which will print the props *before* they are changed. If you want to print the changed props, you should print `nextProps`. Now as `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `true`, React updates `this.props` with `nextProps`. Then `render` is called and hence it logs the changed user. This is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, and it's indeed working as expected. I think my confusion comes from somewhere else then..